# Repeated measure ANOVA with between-subject factor in Python?

Tags: anova, categorical-data, python, repeated-measures

I'm performing repeated measure ANOVA on a 3x3 within-subject factor experiment using [statsmodels's AnovaRM](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.anova.AnovaRM.html). It's a response time experiment, so each participant went through a lot of trials. This package, however, still does not support between-subject factor parameter to group the participants.

Is there any other package in python that support this? Or is there any other way to do this, either manually or using different statistical analysis?

This was the code that I used:

`anova_rt = AnovaRM(data=sns_table_o, 
                     depvar='rt',
                     subject='subject_nr',
                     between='bl_fam',
                     within=['price', 'attribute'],
                     aggregate_func='mean').fit()
print (anova_rt)`

But it just gave "NotImplementedError: Between subject effect not yet supported!" error message.

Answer (score 0):

You could try out the pingouin package: https://pingouin-stats.org/index.html

It seems to cover mixed anovas, which are not yet fully implemented in statsmodels.